# JavaScript Code wont execute when clicking link

Tags: javascript, html

The code below is supposed to allow me to click a text link and that starts my javascript function. However, I get no reaction when I click the links. 
I used this tutorial to help me http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/textsubmit.shtml

```
<html><body>
 <head>  
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function getDSH(selectedField) 
            {
                document.Results.dshToPrint.value = selectedField;
                document.Results.getElementByID(selectedField).disabled = false;
                document.Results.submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('1-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 2 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('2-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('2-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 3 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('3-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('3-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 4 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('4-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('4-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 5 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('5-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 6 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('6-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 7 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('7-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('7-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 8 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('8-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 9 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('9-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('9-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 10 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('10-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('10-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 11 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('11-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 12 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('12-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('12-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('12-3');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 25GBase --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 13 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('13-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('13-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('13-3');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 25GBase --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
<form name = 'Results' method = 'post' action = '/cgi-bin/developer/dsh-generator-d.py'> 
<input type = 'hidden' name = '13-3' value = "[&quot;2015-07-03 14:46:00]" disabled> 
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'dshToPrint' > 
</form> 
</body></html>
```

Is it a syntax error?

**EDIT:** When I click on a link, I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: document.Results.getElementByID is not a function

Comment: Do you know how to use developer tools in the browser of your choice? You will most likely find an error there.

Comment: @area28 according to the google chrome developer tools, I get this error when I click a link: Uncaught TypeError: document.Results.getElementByID is not a function

Comment: This is really old code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try using the Developer's Console from you browser (likely shown with "Ctrl+Shift+I").

For the question: Javascript is case sensitive, so your "getElementByID()" won't work; use "getElementById()" instead. Also, it won't work when calling document.[form].getElementById(), you should call it directly: document.getElementById(id). Nevertheless, you have no ID's set in your HTML, so the clicks will always return 'null' for this parameter in the function.

I recommend that you try some simpler examples first, then get back to this particular one!

Answer (score -1):

Move your `script` tag to the end of the `form`. `JavaScript` comes after `HTML`.

```
<html>
<body>
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('1-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 2 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('2-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
   <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('2-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 3 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('3-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
   <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('3-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 4 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('4-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
   <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('4-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 5 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('5-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 6 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('6-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 7 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('7-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
   <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('7-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 8 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('8-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 9 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('9-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
   <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('9-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 10 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('10-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
   <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('10-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 11 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('11-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
   <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 12 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('12-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
  <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('12-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
  <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('12-3');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 25GBase --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
  <font size = '6' color = 'red'>Loop 13 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------</font><p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('13-1');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testVoltageMargining </a></p> 
  <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('13-2');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 100GBase-4 --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
  <p><a href = "javascript:getDSH('13-3');"> ##! TEST FAIL: /switchCard/testTraffic -l None -s 9208 -d 60 -r 25GBase --allow-mix-speeds --ppm=2000000 </a></p> 
  <form name = 'Results' method = 'post' action = '/cgi-bin/developer/dsh-generator-d.py'> 
  <input type = 'hidden' name = '13-3' value = "[&quot;2015-07-03 14:46:00]" disabled> 
  <input type = 'hidden' name = 'dshToPrint' > 
   </form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function getDSH(selectedField) 
                {
                    document.Results.dshToPrint.value = selectedField;
                    document.Results.getElementByID(selectedField).disabled = false;
                    document.Results.submit();
                }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```